# Error when I create a new project Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I use Eclipse, and when I want to create a new project Android, I have 14 errors. I don't understand why :/

This is a screenshot of the errors :

[image]

How I can fix it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to switch workspace and see.

Comment: @Alex Andre just clean the project and import the necessary library like appcompat7.I think u have to use it that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, but I solved my problem :)
I have created a new project with an Empty Activity and it's working

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added/imported the `appcompat_v7.jar` correctly into your project.When you create a new project your project structure should look something like this :

[image]

As you see inside the `libs` directory `android-support-v4.jar` is there.**Just delete that jar file from there** and it should work for you now.We don't have to add it inside `libs` folder.`appcompat_v7.jar` should be added as a dependency for the project.So if you check inside `Android Dependencies` directory you will find `appcompat_v7.jar`.So after deleting `android-support-v4.jar` your correct project structure now looks like this :

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have not "Android Dependencies", maybe it is because I use Froyo (Android 2.2).

Comment: So did you solve your problem or still struck?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the SDK package manager and install the packages needed for your Android environment. See this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html. Install the required package and it will remove your error

Comment: Ok I will do it, thanks :)